# Error while building unity project(having firebase) for android

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database(for android) for unity. However, while building for android platform, I am getting this error:

> IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.8.0\classes.jar' to 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.8.0\libs\classes.jar'.

I am using Unity's default build system. I looked up online for a solution - It said to add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' to project's build.gradle and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to app-level build.gradle.

But I don't have any gradle files in my project directory.

Please suggest ways how I can solve it.

Comment: check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup it tells you how to setup the android with unity

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the only solution I found is :

- delete all the firebase plugins
- import all the modules again, starting with analytics (this plugin has some problems)

And then... Tada, it works. It's kind of magical, but can't say why it worked...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. My solution was:

1. Exit Unity
2. Navigate to *Assets\Plugins\Android* in your Unity project folder.
3. Delete every *folder*, every *.jar* and every *.aar* that starts with *com.google* or *com.android*
4. Delete all *.meta* files

Voilá